# Get device location and set position on the map

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project where I get the device location and it finds nearby markers. I can't find any way on the Web to convert my position to a **Geopoint**.

```
public async void GetPosition() {
  Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator { DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 0 };
  Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();

  // Needs to be converted to Geopoint
  // Call UpdateLocationData
}

public async void UpdateLocationData(Geopoint geopoint) {
  await MapControl1.TrySetViewAsync(geopoint);
}
```

I tried this code that I found:

```
// Reverse Geocoding
BasicGeoposition myLocation = new BasicGeoposition {
  Longitude = position.Coordinate.Longitude,
  Latitude = position.Coordinate.Latitude
};

Geopoint pointToReverseGeocode = new Geopoint(myLocation);
```

But it says that **Coordinate.Longitude.get is obsolete** on Visual Studio 2015 RC.

Comment: The [`Point`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geocoordinate.point.ASPx) property on the `Coordinate` returns a `Geopoint`.

Comment: @Johnbot geoposition.Coordinate.Point? Damn, I'll check out if that's right ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something a friend and i put together for geolocation using javascript.

```
function getLocation()
{
//Check for geolocation support in browser
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    //getCurrentPosition(function for success, function for error);
    //getCurrentPosition creates a variable named position which has several properties
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation, displayError, {maximumAge:600000, timeout:5000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
} else {
    //Statement for testing else statement and error handling
    document.getElementById('coordinates').innerHTML = "Browser unable to support geolocation.";
}
}

//The argument for displayLocation is a variable created by getCurrentLocation
function displayLocation(position)
{
//Variables to track position
var lati = position.coords.latitude;
var longi = position.coords.longitude;
//If getCurrentPosition is successful / true
alert("Your position has been identified.");
//Displays coordinates
document.getElementById('coordinates').innerHTML = "Latitude: " + lati + " | Longitude: " + longi;
//Displays coordinates on map
showMap(position);
}

function displayError()
{
//If getCurrentPosition fails / false
alert("Unable to locate your position.");
document.getElementById('coordinates').innerHTML = "Unable to locate your position.";
}

function showMap(position)
{
//Variables to track position
var lati = position.coords.latitude;
var longi = position.coords.longitude;
var imageURL= "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + lati + "," + longi + "&zoom=14&size=500x375&sensor=false";
document.getElementById('map').innerHTML = "<img src='" + imageURL + "'>";
}
```

Comment: I'm asking my self why the hell position.Coordinate is obsolete, I'll need to find other way but Microsoft documentation is useless.

Comment: i should add a third argument for options separately however...I'm not sure if the way i did the options will work, i haven't tested that part yet because i just added it.  But the rest worked fine.